# React console log response from NodeJS Server is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, passport.js

I built a login authentication screen with React and ExpressJS with PassportJS, The login route is working fine with authenticating users and giving back a verification or error message on the SERVER, But I can't get a console.log message from the server on the FRONTEND react app, I'm attaching the code down below:

Frontend:

```
import { RegisterNewUser, LoginUser } from "./RegisterAndLoginAPI";

  const onSubmitLogin = (data) => {
    LoginUser(data);
  };
```

Frontend Login API:

```
import Axios from "axios";

  export const LoginUser = async (UserPassedFromClient) => {
   await Axios({
      method: "POST",
          headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data: {
      username: UserPassedFromClient.username,
      password: UserPassedFromClient.password
    },
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "http://localhost:4003/login",
    }).then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log("ERROR FROM THE BACKEND", error);
    })
  };
```

then.((res)=>{console.log(res)}) response from above is not working!
I have also tried to parse the response to json via res.json() which also not worked!

Backend Route:

```
app.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (!user)
      { 
        console.log("No User Exists")
    }
      else {
        req.logIn(user, (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("Successfully Authenticated");
          console.log(req.user);
        });
      }
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

Comment: So when using async/await, you should do with try / catch to capture the error.

Comment: That's because you are not really sending the message back to the frontend.  You are printing the message on the server console.